# Reductive space & Reductive Lie algebra

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces

If $M=G/H$ is a reductive space and $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}+\mathfrak{m}$ be the canonical decomposition, then are  $\mathfrak{g}$ or $\mathfrak{h}$ or both reductive lie algebras? (in this  case, where can I find a proof?)

It is for every ideal $ \mathfrak{a}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ there exists an ideal $  \mathfrak{b}$ sucht that $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}$ or equivalently the adjoint representation is semi-simple

Comment: What is a reductive space?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi According to encyclopedias it means that $\mathfrak h$  $H$-equivariantly splits out of $\mathfrak g$.

Comment: Also I think $G$ and $H$ must be reductive groups, with $H$ closed subgroup of $G$ (so that $G/H$ is a reductive space means $(G,H)$ is a reductive pair).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the definition of a reductive space $G/H$. Some authors require that 
in addition to $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}+\mathfrak{m}$, $[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{m}]\subseteq \mathfrak{m}$, we have that $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h})$ is a reductive pair of Lie algebras, by which they mean that $\mathfrak{g}$ is reductive, and $\mathfrak{h}$ is *reductive in* $\mathfrak{g}$. In this case, since $\mathfrak{h}$ is a $\mathfrak{h}$-submodule of $\mathfrak{g}$, this would imply that $\mathfrak{h}$ itself is reductive.

Comment: but for example take $\mathfrak{g}=e_{1}+e_{2}$ as a vector space and the commutator $[e_{1},e_{2}]=e_{2}$ then $\mathfrak{g}$ is not a reductive lie algebra and take $\mathfrak{h}=e_{1}$ then $Lie(\mathfrak{g})/Lie(\mathfrak{h})$ Is a reductive space

Comment: Yes, it depends on the definition. Do you have a reference where your example $Lie(g)/Lie(h)$ is called a reductive space ?

Comment: @user66943: Your notation such as $Lie(\mathfrak{g})$ seems out of control here.   And as Dietrich points out, precise definitions are needed.